# How to add Previous Balance to the Running Total in Report

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm preparing a report which pulls out data from MySQL database. This report involves a Running Total. The running total is working well except that the Previous Balance is not adding up to the running total.

Actually, I'm new to PHP and MySQL. I was able to do this in MS Access Report. See here: [Previous Balance added to First Row only in Access Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227867/previous-balance-added-to-first-row-only-in-access-report).

I use the following code for the report:

```
SELECT
    Pmt_Date,
    Description,
    Amount_In,
    Amount_Out,
    (@sum := @sum + Balance) AS BalanceTotal
FROM
    view_transactions
JOIN(
SELECT @sum := 0
) AS tx
WHERE
    Sch_Code = ? AND SESSION = ? AND Term = ? AND Bank = ? AND(
        Pmt_Date BETWEEN '".$st_start_date."' AND '".$st_end_date."'
    )
ORDER BY
    Pmt_Date ASC
```

I use the following code to get the Previous Balance:

```
SELECT
    SUM(Balance) AS PreBalance
FROM
    view_transactions
WHERE
    Sch_Code = ? AND SESSION = ? AND Term = ? AND Bank = ? AND(Pmt_Date < '".$st_start_date."')
```

I know with my approach, I can only get something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcRBb.png (which I'm currently getting), but the desired output should be something like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuT5E.png

(COMPARE THE BALANCE COLUMNS, PLEASE)

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing that out. I figured it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested on how I solved it:

I changed this part:

```
SELECT @sum := 0
```

to this:

```
SELECT @sum := COALESCE(NULLIF(SUM(Balance), ''), 0)
FROM
    view_transactions
WHERE
    Sch_Code = ? AND Session = ? AND Term = ? AND Bank = ? AND (Pmt_Date < '".$st_start_date."')
```

Comment: You should replace `'".$st_start_date."'` with another parameter.

Comment: Yes. Why do you have everything else replaced with parameters except the last value? Every piece of data should be separated and bound using parameters.